# How do pass parameters from 1 form to another?

Tags: c#, .net

My program has a main form where I keep a repository of values from other sub forms. For some reason the sub form is giving me an error:

> an object reference is required for the non-static field

This is my main form:

```c#
public partial class frm_SystemLog : Form
{
    public frm_SystemLog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        // suppose to get value from other forms
        get { return this.textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }   

    private void frm_SystemLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log frm_LoginMenu = new Log();
        frm_LoginMenu.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This is my sub form:

```c#
public partial class Log : Form
{
    public Log()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this is where the error happens
        frm_SystemLog.TextBoxValue = "SomeValue";
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a property in your log form then set its value when you are accessing it

```
//in log form 
public String MyValue{get;set;}
```

then in properties of your button2 of log form choose dialogresult and set it to ok
then in your button2 click event

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyValue = "SomeValue";
        //no need to close ,dialogresult will do it...

    }
```

then  in your frm_SystemLog  form do this

```
private void frm_SystemLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Log frm_LoginMenu = new Log();
        frm_LoginMenu.ShowDialog();
        if(frm_LoginMenu.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.TextBoxValue = frm_LoginMenu.MyValue;
        }

    }
```

this should solve your problem.

Comment: I have to create a trigger variable cause when i recall the back to frm_SystemLog it reloads the Log form... but the code was useful.

Answer (score 0):

`frm_SystemLog.TextBoxValue` isn't accessible from `button2_Click`, because it's in a different class.

Comment: i figure that was the problem...appreciate it, but i was asking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're trying to reference an object on your parent form class, not an instance of your class. In that case, the only objects you can reference are static ones, hence the error you're getting.

You need an actual reference to the instance of your parent form. Change your `Log` class as follows:

```
public partial class Log : Form
{
    private frm_SystemLog parentForm;

    public Log(frm_SystemLog parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.parentForm = parentForm;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Then instantiate your sub form using:

```
Log frm_LoginMenu = new Log(this);
```

Read ["Understanding Classes, Methods, and Properties in C#"](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/anandctutorials/article.php/c5829/Understanding-Classes-Methods-and-Properties-in-C.htm) for more information, in particular:

> There are two kinds of methods in C#. They are:
>
> - Instance Method
> - Static Method
>
> Instance Methods are methods declared outside the main method and can be accessed only by creating an object of the corresponding class.
>
> Class methods also are declared outside the main method but can be accessed without creating an object of the class. They should be declared with the keyword static and can be accessed using the classname.methodname syntax.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff @Henryyottabyte. I gave you the code to modify. How *exactly* did it not solve your problem?